# Include both joined tables in Rails JSON API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting the following Active Record Association error when trying to join two tables (with a polymorphic relationship) and include all data from both tables in a JSON API response:

```
Association named 'categories' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Here is the controller action that I am trying to call:

```
def index

    @items = Item.includes(:categories)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @items.to_json }
    end

end
```

And here are the two models that I am trying to join:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name

    has_many :items, :as => :linkable

end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :due_date, :linkable_id, :linkable_type, ...

    belongs_to :linkable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true

end
```

Specifically, I want to return each Item in the database along with its Category.  I have tried everything that I can think of.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't defined the 'categories' relationship in the Item model(its linkable). Checkout http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
def index
    @items = Item.includes(:linkable).where(:linkable_type => 'Category')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => @items.to_json(include: :linkable) }
    end
end
```

The name of your association is actually :linkable for the Item model, and not :categories (especially because it's a belongs_to so it would be :category).